What is the etymology of calling the carotis "sleep artery" in Slavic languages?
I noticed that, in many Slavic languages, the anatomical feature commonly known by its Latin name 'arteria carotis' in English, has a name that literally translates as 'sleep artery'. This includes сонная артерия in Russian and cognates in Belorussian, Bulgarian, Polish, Croatian and Ukrainian. It's not ubiquitous in soviet bloc states though - if we can believe Wikipedia, it's not the common name in Czech, Macedonian, or some non-slavic ex-USSR languages.
Interestingly, it seems that 'Schlafader' is also a (rarely used) German term, but it's the name of a different artery, the arteria temporalis superficialis. This seems to be connected to the fact that the temple is called 'Schläfe' in German, as indeed the more common term appears to be 'Schläfenader'.
I am aware that pressing on the carotis artery for a short duration of time can cause unconsciousness, but I don't want to simply assume that this is the name origin. It would be a very convenient just-so-story.
So, what is the actual origin behind the name?

I don’t think it’s commonly known in English by its Latin name, arteria carotis. The common name for it (to the extent that we talk about it at all outside of medical tv shows) is carotid artery.

It is absolutely the same etymology as "carotid artery" itself. English "carotid" -> French "carotide" -> Latin "carotides" -> Greek "κᾰρωτῐ́δες" (karotides) from "κᾰρόω" (karóō), meaning to plunge into deep sleep.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carotid
The only difference is that Slavic languages used a calque translation instead of borrowing the original word.
